# No page number displayed after applying header and footer

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, chapters

After applying a new header and footer, no page number is displayed in my document; only the updated header and footer. And there is another problem: there is no header or footer displayed on chapter pages but here I can see the page number.

I need both header and footer and page number on all the pages.

This is what I use at the moment:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,roman]{report}
%\userpakage{time}
\usepackage{thesis}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[left=1.57in, right=0.98in,top=0.98in,bottom=1.57in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\chead{\textbf Header }
\cfoot{\textbf Footer }
```

[image: http://latex-community.org/forum/download/file.php?id=5937]

[image: http://latex-community.org/forum/download/file.php?id=5938]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Note that the [`epsfig`](http://ctan.org/pkg/epsfig) package is severely outdated. Using [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) would suffice, since it also loads [`graphics`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphics).

Answer (score 3):

Under the default document classes (including `report`), the page style `plain` is used for chapter title pages. Even though you're using [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) to display your headers, the behaviour of the document class is still to typeset the main chapter page in `plain`. If you *really* wish to have the `plain` page style be the same as your `fancy`, then you can do:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr
\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\chead{\textbf{Header}}% Centre header
\cfoot{\textbf{Footer}\ \thepage}% Centre footer
\pagestyle{fancy}
\makeatletter
\let\ps@plain\ps@fancy% plain page style = fancy
\makeatother
```

Note that I've added `\thepage` to `\cfoot` to add the page number to the `fancy` page style footer. Also, `\textbf` is a macro that takes an argument, so I've modified it as such.

Comment: Also doing `\fancypagestyle{plain}{...}` would solve the issue.

Comment: @egreg: Yes, and require a duplication of the `fancy` page style.

Comment: @Werner thanks but this is not working each chapter footer start form number 1 to so on..

Comment: @chamara54: It might be that `\usepackage{thesis}` is causing this or setting something to that effect for `\chapter`. Do you have a reference to `thesis.sty` that one can look at?

Comment: \documentclass[a4paper,12pt,roman]{report}
%\userpakage{time}
\usepackage{thesis}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[left=1.57in, right=0.98in,top=0.98in,bottom=1.57in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\chead{\textbf Header }
\cfoot{\textbf Footer }
\linespread{1.3}
\begin{document}
\include{Cover}
\include{title}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\include{declration}
\include{abstract}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\include{chap1}
\include{chap2}
\end{document}

Comment: The command `\pagenumbering{roman}` resets the page numbers to start from 1. However, I doubt whether you have `\pagenumbering{arabic}` for *each* chapter, do you?